# Commit message with Redmine Ticket

Tags: linux, svn, redmine, redmine-plugins

I would like to integrate Redmine with SVN in a manner that the commit message automatically gets posted in the Redmine Ticket ID. Kindly let me know if there are any plugins or hooks up which can be used for me to achieve the same

Answer (score 1):

Such functionality is built in.

Go to **Admin | Settings** click on **Repositories** tab, and there you will see following section:

*Referencing and fixing issues in commit messages
Referencing keywords*

By default, there are:
**refs,references,IssueID**

So when you perform svn commit, and say

> refs #23

such change will be displayed on issue no=23, once you refresh repositories and visit issue again.

There is also way to automate it, so svn or git, post-commit hook refreshes repositores for you...

Full doc here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_setup_automatic_refresh_of_repositories_in_Redmine_on_commit

Such way if you track changes, you can see all code that was changed, regarding some issue...

For example:

[image]

And you can click on (**diff**) to see that particular code...

Then, furthermore, you can copy URL's when you click diff, so you can discuss code with your peers...

Cheers :)